# Gradle Plugins in the Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

When in use, Android Studio displays a dialog box that prompts to update the gradle 2.3.3 plugin. When the update button is clicked, nothing happens. How do I update the grade plugin in Android Studio ?

Comment: Please update question with version of the tools being used to make it more specific.

Comment: ok I updated my Question with the version of the gradle ..@Aakash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Build.Gradle (Project) and search something like this

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
```

it should be highlighted, just put the cursor over it and it´s going to tell you what is the most recent version

Comment: yes i done this kind of searching bt i am not getting the updates of the gradle plugins..